sys.stdin.readline() in an inittab
I am using sys.stdin.readline() to to hang the execution of a Python script, to keep it persistent. When I put this script in an inittab and it comes time to log into Linux after rebooting, hitting enter actually makes readline() read the input! Why is this? What is the proper way to keep a Python script daemonized?

What is the script doing, other than waiting on standard input? If nothing, why does it need to be persistent? If something, why do you need to block on standard input at all?

Programs running from inittab have the console as their standard input and output.

Daemons normally have an infinite loop in their top-level code or main function. That keeps them running forever.

Where did you think it was waiting for input from?

@Barmar From my keyboard. It was messing with my ability to type in my username and password.

@chepner "What is the script doing, other than waiting on standard input?" It is keeping some things loaded in shared memory (shm).

So if that's what you expected, why are you surprised that it messes with this? If two programs are both waiting for keyboard input, only one of them can get it.

@Barmar I never had the problem before. It seems to be a Linux login console issue, then.

You were just lucky. When two processes are waiting for input from the same keyboard, it's arbitrary which one receives it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
